# I want to send data from one activity to another activity without launching second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, buttonclick

I want to send data from one activity to another activity without launching second activity. for example i want to send the value of i which increments after every button click should get this value in another activity.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without launching Activity what is use of incremented value on second Activity?

Comment: Why would you want to send data to an Activity that you are not going to start?

Comment: You can try LocalBroadcast for this purpose

Comment: without launch activity where you saw the data?

Comment: What is the use of that value if second activity is not evoked ?

Comment: better you go for SharedPreferences

Comment: um.. what ever the purpose is you can do it in many ways some of them are :
1. you can use static
2. shared pref (as mentioned in other anwsers)

Comment: I want to add same number of textviews in another activity as the no. of clicks.

Comment: So that means you are going to evoke that second activity ?

Comment: I will call second activity not on the button click. In some other condition.

Comment: static u should not use i think.

Comment: ok in that case you can use shared pref or use static variable which will hold the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118005/discussion-between-balaji-and-umesh-chauhan).

Comment: You can make variable "i" as static and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve the values.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be good idea to save this data on SharedPreferences or in Database. After launching second activity - you can get this values from SP or Database. 
It will be better idea, because you need to save many different values and objects later.

Comment: I think database is bit heavier task.